# how does connection pool work with mysql replicationDriver

Tags: mysql, replication

I wonder how connection pool work with mysql replicationDriver. If I set connection pool to 100. How many connections would be consumed in master and slaves individually?

```
<bean id="widgetDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">  
<property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver"/>  
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://db1-private:3306,db2-private:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&amp;failOverReadOnly=false&amp;roundRobinLoadBalance=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"/>
```

Comment: Although this question is something related to computer programming. It is not the type of question SO is expected. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it is not a question related to master/slave setup? what kind of question you expected? batman vs superman who will win??

Answer (score 0):

It would depend entirely on how many of those connections were read-only and read-write respectively. The read-only connections would be to the slave(s) and the read-write ones to the master. This is a dynamic property of the system, not a static property, and can't be answered in advance.

Comment: hi EJP, I edited my post with configuration. there is no setup for read and write respectively. I can only set maxPoolsize to 1000. I wonder how would be those 1000 split up on master/slave. would be 1k for each. or a combination.

Comment: @ian.huang Evidently I have failed to make myself clear. You are asking an unanswerable question. How many connections are read-only and how many read-write is a function of the dynamic state of your system. It isn't static and it isn't ascertainable from your configuration.